# Is it better to have lots of Azure Functions in one project or many?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have written eight different Azure Functions in one .NET project.  They work great but I was wondering if it makes more sense from a performance optimization standpoint to put each function in it's own project.  Any ideas in this would regard would be most appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why it could have an impact on performance. It could be a difference when you put them all in the same appservice plan. 
A reason to put them in separate projects can be that you want to deploy and evolve them independently. We try to make them as independent as possible putting them in seperate projects or even in a different git repo with separate pipelines will make it easier to evolve them independent.